# How to Configure Session Behavior and Token Lifetimes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

When using [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom):

- How do I configure the [Session Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#session-behavior)?
- How do I configure [Token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#token-lifetimes-configuration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are described by [Azure Active Directory B2C: Manage SSO and token customization with custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration).

Comment: New link is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens-custom-policy